# sql iteration vs group by, massive performance difference

Tags: sql, performance, group-by, iteration

I've been given a simple task: to select 'id', min and max values for every unique id in the table. So I wrote simple `group by` but the query took ages to execute (30-60 seconds)

```
SELECT     CHPDataElement.DataElementID, MIN(CHPDataElementData.UTCDataTime) AS MinDataTime, MAX(CHPDataElementData.UTCDataTime) AS MaxDataTime
FROM         CHPDataElement INNER JOIN
                      CHPDataElementData ON CHPDataElement.DataElementID = CHPDataElementData.DataElementID
GROUP BY CHPDataElement.DataElementID

order by 
CHPDataElement.DataElementID
```

So I started working on improvement. And came up with simple iteration that returns the same data in 0.3-0.5 seconds.

```
declare @result table
(
    DataElementID int,
    MinDataTime datetime NULL,
    MaxDataTime datetime null
)

declare @currentID int
declare @nextID int
declare @time datetime

insert into @result (DataElementID, MinDataTime, MaxDataTime)
select DataElementID,null,null from CHPDataElement
order by DataElementID

select top 1 @currentID=DataElementID from @result 

while @currentID is not null
begin
    print @currentID


    select top 1 @time=UTCDataTime  from CHPDataElementData
    where DataElementID = @currentID 
    order by UTCDataTime asc

    update @result set MinDataTime = @time
    where DataElementID = @currentID

    select top 1 @time=UTCDataTime  from CHPDataElementData
    where DataElementID = @currentID 
    order by UTCDataTime desc

    update @result set MaxDataTime = @time
    where DataElementID = @currentID



    set @nextID = null
    select top 1 @nextID=DataElementID from @result where DataElementID > @currentID
    set @currentID = @nextID
end

select * from @result
```

Could anybody explain why the 'group by' is so inefficient compared to the second query?

Comment: have you looked at the query execution plan? What is the statistical distribution of `DataElementID`?

Comment: Hi, the execution plan shows that 92% of the query cost is in 'Clusterd Index Scan on CHPDataElementData.PK_CHPDataElementData'

Comment: And presumably, in the efficient queries you get a number of 'Clustered Index Seek on ...'

Comment: Yes, that's correct. it's Clustered Index Seek with cost of 9%

Comment: Are your statistics up to date? I'm just thinking of reasons why the query engine is making bad desicions.

Comment: Yes, they are up to date...

Comment: well, it looks like the query engine doesen't appreciate how large the groups will be so, does all the grouping work up front in one big scan. The problem then is that the aggregate functions don't benefit from the indexes you have on the column. Perhaps if you had a convering index on `DataElementID, UTCDateTime` then the engine could use that to optimise the group, then the aggregates in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Give CHPDataElementData an index on DataElementID.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the DataElementID is part of the primary Key 'DataElementID (ASC), UTCDataTime (ASC)'. In addition to that I've got index on 'UTCDataTime (ASC), DataElementID (ASC)'

Comment: @AdamBilinski which is why your second method is faster.

Comment: @Jodrell could you please elaborate?

Comment: @AdamBilinski, see my comment on the question.

Comment: If your DataElementData table is indexed as you say, then I'm baffled that the set-based query is so slow. Is DataElementID the primary key of DataElement?  Is there a foreign key constraint defined?

Comment: Yes, it is the primary key on DataElement and there is a relationship between them (on DataElementID)

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to `CHPDataElementData` on `DataElementID, UTCDateTime`,

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_CHPDataElementData_DataElementID_UTCDataTime
    ON CHPDataElementData
(
    DataElementID ASC,
    UTCDataTime ASC
)
```

then use this statement,

```
SELECT
            CHPDataElementData.DataElementID,
            MIN(CHPDataElementData.UTCDataTime) AS MinDataTime,
            MAX(CHPDataElementData.UTCDataTime) AS MaxDataTime
    FROM
            CHPDataElementData
    GROUP BY
            CHPDataElementData.DataElementID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: @AdamBilinski, so what query plan did you get?